# Cscope Syntax hightlight search within search

Tags: vim, vi, cscope

I am using CSCOPE for my project and I have few question.

1) Can I color the search result (mostly when I serach using 
":cs f s " i.e. within the open file.

2) Is there a way to search within search? Like I search "ret_val" and it gave 1000 result, instead of going each line, can I search some more like folder name etc?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you use the tool, but generally, the answer is yes.

1) You could either redirect results to file, lets say `out.cscope` then create syntax file for file type *.csope OR, use a function to run the tool, then locally set up the buffer with adequate `hi` and `match` options

2) If you saved search results in a cscope file then you can search it normally. Otherwise you can `redir` output to new tab/split and again search the buffer (which now doesn't need to have externally associated file. I suggest you to use `vim-foldsearch` plugin to fold out anything (not) in the match. You can even delete folded sections (with or without any number of context lines) so that only stuff you are interested in finally remains in the buffer (i.e. it behaves like filter). Alternatively you can use `unite` plugin and it filtering source `lines` which filters lines as you type the keyword. Actually, I would personally go with that option as it provides most interactive way of working.